# How to get List of all tables in the Entity data framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

I need to get the list of All tables in the Entity Data Framework.

I know that in Linq2SQL we can use something like this.
var dataContext = new DataContext();
var dataContextTableNames = (from tables in dataContext.Mapping.GetTables()
                             select tables.TableName).ToList();

But, I need to get list of all tables in Entity Data Framework. There is any work around to get similar list in Entity Data Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

Perhaps this can be of use to find the number of objects in Storage space

```
   var count = GetEntitySetCount(myObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace);

   public static int GetEntitySetCount(MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   {
        var count = 0;

        // Get a collection of the entity containers from storage space.
        var containers = workspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.SSpace);

        foreach(var container in containers)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("EntityContainer Name: {0} ",
            //                  container.Name);

            foreach(var baseSet in container.BaseEntitySets)
            {
                if(baseSet is EntitySet)
                {
                    count++;

                    //Console.WriteLine(
                    //    "  EntitySet Name: {0} , EntityType Name: {1} ",
                    //    baseSet.Name, baseSet.ElementType.FullName);
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

To retrieve the number of tables in the database, you can do the following in .Net 4.0

```
myObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'");
```

Using .Net 3.5

```
var connection = ((EntityConnection)myObjectContext.Connection).StoreConnection as SqlConnection;

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'", connection);

connection.Open();

var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

connection.Close();
```

Comment: it gets the list of tables from the database. I need to get all the lsit of all tables from the model.

Comment: Unless you're using the database for non EF related stuff, that will be count - 1 (for the EdmMetadata table)

Comment: The problem is I have updated the database, I deleted some tables from the database. But, I do not wish to update the Model until I know that the number of tables in both Database and EF are not the same. So, I need to know how to count the number of tables in EF now.